# Dependency Injection wth NLog

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, nlog

I've got a .NET Core web app that I'm trying to add logging to via NLog.
In previous projects, I've just used something like the following at the top of every class:

```cs
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I'm trying to follow more best practices with this project where possible.

My question is, how can I inject a logger which has the fully qualified name of the class that it's being injected into?

In my startup.cs file, so far I've got the following:

```cs
services.AddScoped<BLL.Logging.NLogLogger>();
```

At the moment, the `NLogLogger` class creates an instance of an NLog Logger via `GetCurrentClassLogger()`, which when used will only ever report the name as "BLL.Logging.NLogLogger" rather than the actual class that the logger is being injected into.

To simplify the question and make it a bit more generic:
How can you pass in the name of the class that .NET Core is going to inject a class into?

I've thought about something like the below, but not sure how to achieve it:

```cs
services.AddScoped<BLL.Logging.NLogLogger>(serviceProvider => new BLL.Logging.NLogLogger("class name here"));
```

Comment: You can't. There is no way to do this using the built-in ASP.NET Core container. You will have to use a 'real' DI container for this, like Autofac or Simple Injector.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using DI specify `ILogger<T>` type instead of `Logger`, where `T` is the class type that uses the logger, so NLog will know about the class. For example:

```cs
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TodoController(ILogger<TodoController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

References:

- [Getting started with ASP.NET Core (csproj vs2017)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017)#5-write-logs)
- [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#6-write-logs)
- [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 3](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#6-write-logs)

Comment: Ah great, that's exactly what I needed, it's much cleaner than the solution I came up with before I saw your answer.

One thing that bothers me is that the logger.LogError() method forces you to specify an eventID as a paremeter - generally I wouldn't do this and instead use the ${activityid} layout renderer, so for now, I'm just going to set the value to 0 for example - any thoughts/suggestions regarding the eventID?

Comment: @Steviebob u can use this version of method https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs#L273 . Moreover, LogError is an extension method, and you are free to  define you own version, if you want to use another method signature.

Comment: @oleksa [ILogger<T>](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerOfT.cs) is defined in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and doesn't relate to Nlog. Check your `usings` and nuget packages. Look into [Introduction to Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging) if you are new with logging staff in asp.net core. And feel free to create  a new SO question if needed

Comment: above link is broken. New one: [Logging/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs)

Comment: above link is broken (as well).  New one:
[dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 9):

I think I've figured out an acceptable solution, although not exactly the way I asked the question.

First of all, I create a "LoggerFactory", which has a single method called "GetLogger" (which creates the concrete NLog Logger and accepts a class name as a parameter), and I inject this factory instead of the logger directly.

**LoggerFactory:**

```cs
public class LoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    public ILogger GetLogger(string fullyQualifiedClassName)
    {
        return new NLogLogger(fullyQualifiedClassName);
    }
}
```

**NLogLogger:**

```cs
public class NLogLogger : ILogger, INLogLogger
{
    NLog.Logger mylogger;
    public NLogLogger(string fullyQualifiedClassName)
    {
        mylogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(fullyQualifiedClassName);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
services.AddScoped<BLL.Logging.ILoggerFactory>();
```

The in my controller class, I've got:

```cs
    private BLL.Logging.ILogger logger;//my NLogLogger inherits this interface

    public HomeController(BLL.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.GetLogger(this.GetType().FullName);
    }
```

So what I've effectively now done, is rather than injecting the actual Logger itself (Which @Steven indicated would not be possible the way I was trying to do it), I've instead injected the utility to create an instance of a logger which wraps NLog.

I've still got the responsibility to create the logger within the class, but at least I've decoupled from the underlying logging framework (NLog).

Comment: This is seriously not what you want! Looks like you have now a reference of NLog in your controller, and you are breaking up the Microsoft Logging interface.

Comment: @SteveRakebrandt The OP is asking for DI of *NLog* loggers. So as far as answering that question goes this is more of a solution than the accepted answer. And imho there is no upside of sticking with the MS Logging interface. `NLog` has good features that you want to take advatage of if you opt for that framework and don't want them to be obmitted by having your loggers stuffed in a generic MS interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a dependency on NLog in your controller (so you depend on Microsoft abstractions instead) :

In your command handler / controller

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class MyHandler(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    public void Handler()
    {
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("myCustomLogger");
        logger?.LogDebug("My log");
    }
}
```

`nlog.config`

```
<rules>
  <logger name="myCustomLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="myCustomFile" final="true" /> <!-- final so that myCustomLogger only logs in this rule -->
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>


<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="C:\MyApp\logs\log.log"
          layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  
  <target xsi:type="File" name="myCustomFile" fileName="C:\MyApp\logs\lastHttpCall.log"
          layout="${message}" replaceFileContentsOnEachWrite="true" />
</targets>
```

Comment: The standard approach is using Microsoft LoggerFactory (Call `AddLogging` when empty `ServiceCollection`), and then add NLog as Logging Provider using `AddNLog` /  `UseNLog`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application