# Unit test checking for occurrence of edge case

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have a function for raycasting on a grid with Bresenham's algorithm. I want to optimize for specific cases when the line is orthogonal or diagonal; of course, this logic won't be returned/exposed to the user.

Is it possible to detect the optimization edge case throught a unit test? E.g. Look for a specific `Debug.WriteLine` marker when calling the function.

I'm new to unit testing and I might be missing the point (testing functionality exposed to the user) but asserting that my edge cases work as expected can be invaluable - especially when actively developing the optimizations.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
public IEnumerable<Coordinate> RayCast (Coordinate source, Coordinate direction) {
    if (direction.X == 0 || direction.Y == 0) {
        Debug.WriteLine ("Orthogonal_Edge_Case");
        //Simple iteration across 1 axis
        ...
        yield break;
    }
    if (Math.Abs(direction.X) == Math.Abs(direction.Y)) {
        Debug.WriteLine ("Diagonal_Edge_Case");
        //Simple diagonal iteration
        ...
        yield break;
    }        
    //Standard Bresenham's algorithm
    ...
    yield break;
}
```

...

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRayCast () {
    var source = new Coordinate (0,0);

    var orthogonal = new Coordinate (0,1);
    CoordinateUtil.RayCast (source, orthogonal);
    //Check that the Orthogonal_Edge_Case marker was emitted

    var diagonal = new Coordinate (1,1);
    CoordinateUtil.RayCast (source, diagonal);
    //Check that the Diagonal_Edge_Case marker was emitted

    //Usual tests for RayCast
    ...
}
```

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2019's unit test kit but I'm curious if this is possible with any .NET tool

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I looked into the Moq and logging solutions and I think I have a good idea about how to hack in unit test edge case detection. For this project, I can see that it's overkill but I will keep these tools in mind for larger projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Hold some sort of state using a property in CoordinateUtil which will allow you to check what was the last edge detected. This will however break the [Command Query Responsibility Segregation pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).
2. Inject an edge case detector (which you can easily mock with mocking framework). The example below use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).
3. Inject an [ILogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) which will allow you to log some timing information amongst other things (very similar to option2 but with [slightly different set up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41534919/283787)).

Below shows how option 2 works. You may feel it is overkill but it is robust and how things are generally done in large projects. Also note that you are now exposing internals to the outside world, just to help with internal optimisation. If so then this may not be appropriate.

```
public class CoordinateUtil
{
    private readonly IEdgeCaseDetector edgeCaseDetector;

    // This is the important bit where you inject an edge case detector
    public CoordinateUtil(IEdgeCaseDetector edgeCaseDetector)
    {
        this.edgeCaseDetector = edgeCaseDetector;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Coordinate> RayCast(Coordinate source, Coordinate direction)
    {
        if (direction.X == 0 || direction.Y == 0)
        {
            edgeCaseDetector.Detect("Orthogonal_Edge_Case");
            //Simple iteration across 1 axis
            yield break;
        }
        if (Math.Abs(direction.X) == Math.Abs(direction.Y))
        {
            edgeCaseDetector.Detect("Diagonal_Edge_Case");
            //Simple diagonal iteration
            yield break;
        }

        //Standard Bresenham's algorithm
        yield break;
    }
}

public interface IEdgeCaseDetector
{
    void Detect(string message);
}

public class EdgeCaseDetector
{
    public void Detect(string message)
    {
       // If you wanted to you could simply save the edge cases to a public property here
       // Or you might want to log them when you code runs outside of the unit test
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class CoordinateUtilTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void RayCast_WhenOthogonal_DetectsEdgeCase()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<IEdgeCaseDetector>();
        var coordinateUtil = new CoordinateUtil(mock.Object);
        var source = new Coordinate(1, 1);

        // Act
        // Remember the ToArray because we need to evaluate the enumerable
        // before we can check if the edge case was detected.
        coordinateUtil.RayCast(source, new Coordinate(0, 0)).ToArray();

        // Assert
        mock.Verify(x => x.EdgeDetected("Orthogonal_Edge_Case"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing internal logic to the external world only for sake of the tests, wouldn't be best approach.
You should test only against public api and behaviour.
For performance tests it can be tricky, but doable. For example what behaviour consumer of the method under the test will observe if you execute Standard Bresenham's algorithm for edge cases?

Does execution will takes more then 500 milliseconds? If so, write test for it and check that for edge cases execution takes less then 500 milliseconds.

If you can not find such observable behaviour I would not write tests for it, and just trust developer who ever write or maintain this code. All developers smart people and try their best.