# Check log message in unit test by Nlog C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, .net-4.0

I am looking for a way to test Log message by using `Nlog`

Typically, all of my classes has a private member `_logger`

Ex:

```
using NLog;
public class MyClass {
    private readonly Logger _logger;
    public MyClass(){
        this._logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }
}
```

Whenever I need to log the message, I'll call

```
_logger.info('message')
```

Since C# isn't allowed me to inject the Log object dynamically, I was wondering how to test the message in the unit test? I am thinking somehow this way.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLogMessage() {
    var testGerrits = MyClass();
    // mock the logger?
    Assert.AreEqual(logger[0], "expected message");
}
```

Comment: Why not use `ILogger<T>` and pass it as dependency in ctor and then mock it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Not sure if I understand it correctly, can you provide an example?

Comment: You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534253/dependency-injection-with-nlog)

Comment: Ok, thanks, it helps. Do you want to answer it? Maybe add a little mock syntax and I will select it.